# Perl MultiLine Regex Statement

Tags: regex, perl, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I'm having some trouble getting a multiline regex statement to work for me.

Basically, I'm trying to remove empty lines following a ) ->. Matching the multiline section has been a bit tricky. Here's what I have so far:

```
perl -00 -p -i -e 's/\) ->(?=[^\n]*\n\n)$/\) ->\n/m' $filename
```

Here's my input/output:

```
Input:
setUp = 
  config: (cb) ->

    randomFunction (cb)->

       cb?()

  nestedObject: 
    key: (cb) ->

      cb?()


Output:
setUp = 
  config: (cb) ->
    cb?()

  nestedObject: 
    key: (cb) ->
      cb?()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do line by line processing with a flip-flop range, removing all blank lines as the end condition:

```
perl -i -pe '/\) ->\s*$/...!s/^\s*$//' file.txt
```

Perhaps a little easier to read:

```
perl -i -pe 'm{\) ->\s*$}...!s/^\s*$//' file.txt
```

Comment: This works great! Could you walk me through the syntax just a bit more, for the sake of learning a bit more about perl

Comment: I'm a little confused {}...! construct. The way I understand it is that it's matching the ') ->\s*$' and then once matched, only "grabs" the s/^\s*$/ (ie: empty line)... I'm new to perl

Comment: If you're new to perl, the above definitely could be a little confusing.  However, the important details are documented at [`perlop #Range operators`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators)

Answer (score 2):

Move the newline characters out of the look-ahead. Try

```
    s/\) ->(?=[^\n]*)\n\n/\) ->\n/mg;
```

Characters in the look-ahead are not replaced in a substitution.

(Actually, I don't see why you even need a look-ahead.

```
    s/\) ->.*\n\n/\) ->\n/mg;
```

also does the job, and any non-zero length sequence that matched the look-ahead would also make the whole pattern match fail.)

You also may want to use the `/g` flag, since you want to do this substitution more than once in the document.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this replacement:

```
s/\) ->\R\K\R+//g
```

`\R` is a shortcut for an atomic group that contains several common types of newlines
`\K` removes all on the left from match result